# Using different environment in development and production with SSIS

Tags: ssis, connection-string

My SSIS (2005) package uses variables and expressions to set some values at run-time (e.g. connection string, database name)

I have found out that the package validation does not use the expressions so I need to supply a "default" value (which is never used at run-time)

My problem is now how to set a default value that will work on both my development machine and in production.

An example:
I have a Connection Manager where the `ConnectionString` property is set to the expression `@[User::CurrentConnectionString]`.

At run-time the CurrentConnectionString is fetched from a database.

The package validator use the default value for the `ConnectionString` property so I need to put something there or the validation will fail.

My problem is now that I need different connection strings on my development machine and on the production server (e.g. different user name).

Currently I manually edit the dtsx file before deploying it to production. 
**Is there a better way?**

Comment: You should use `XML configuration` for deploying the packages in different environment .They offer great deal of flexibility in changing the ssis variables without opening the `package`

Comment: @praveen, the problem is not to set the variables. I can do that from the command line. The problem is that the validation runs before the variable is assigned to the property.

Comment: SSIS package will throw error only when you `open` the dtsx package in `different` environment becuase of different variables values .If you simply run your deployed package in production with xml conf enabled ,the package won't throw error.Btw it's not a good practise to edit the package in prod.Whatever changes u need to make ,do it in `development` environment and then deploy it in prod with the `xml config`   files